# HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR / Not able to query data due to "*"-symbol

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena, hive-metastore

I am making my first steps with AWS Glue, Athena and Quicksight... Currently I try to visualize data of a building which creates JSON-Files using the SNON-format (example message down below). The message-format uses "*" to represent a default language region. Glue successfully crawls the data but as soon as I want to query it in Athena the following message appears due to the *-symbol:

HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR: com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: Error: name expected at the position 200 of 'array,entityName:struct<*:string>,entityID:string,measureUnit:string,value:array>>>' but * is found. (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)

Does anyone know a workaround? Thanks in advance!

Example message:

```
[ 
{
"messageTime":"2020-01-20T14:10:30.864Z",
"messageID":"urn:uuid:75a82b1b-d617-4c06-9b27-db2abea3bb14",
"message":{
          "valueTime":["2020-01-09T07:53:24.246Z"],
          "entityName":{"*":"Temperature"},
          "entityID":"urn:uuid:461bc368-0925-484b-ad96-c03fef490ece", 
          "measureUnit":"°C",
          "value":["30"]}  
}
]
```

More information about the SNON-Format can be found [here](http://www.snon.org/)

Comment: were you able to run show create table <table-name>statement ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the same error message as described earlier occurs...

Comment: So this looks like your table columns are filled with special characters where it should not be. Can you confirm if you are crawling cloud trail data in s3 using AWS Glue?

Comment: I am crawling s3 data using AWS Glue, but it is not cloud trail data...The data is uploaded to s3 from another service.

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to make sure that these data has no special characters present in column or keys other than underscore. Athena will not support special characters in column names.